# Drop down menu "broken" in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

I have a drop down menu that's working just fine in Chrome and Safari, but when testing it in Firefox and IE, the dropdown box is longer down and therefore unreachable.

```
 <!--produkter dropdown -->                                                   
<div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenudiv">
<a href="raw_frames.php">RAW Frames</a>
<a href="project321.php">PROJECT 321</a>
<a href="camsports.php">CAMSPORTS</a>
<a href="foss.php">FOSS</a>
</div>


<!--medie dropdown -->                                                
<div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenudiv" style="width: 113px;">
<a href="testride.php?id=100">TEST RIDE</a>
<a href="howto.php">HOW TO</a>
<a href="riders_view.php">RIDERS VIEW</a>
</div>

.dropmenudiv{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 36px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 26px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #424141, #262626); /* Mozilla */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#424141), to(#262626)); /* Chrome-Safari */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#424141', endColorstr='#262626'); /* IE */
    width: 137px;
    visibility: hidden;
}


    .dropmenudiv a{
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        text-indent: 5px;
        padding: 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    * html .dropmenudiv a{ /*IE only hack*/
        width: 100%;
    }

    .dropmenudiv a:hover{
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #545454, #2c2c2c); /* Mozilla */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#545454), to(#2c2c2c)); /* Chrome-Safari */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#545454', endColorstr='#2c2c2c'); /* IE */
    }
```

I have read a lot around the net and can see that a lot of other people have similar problems with Firefox not showing the div the same place as in Chrome and other browsers.

Comment: For me even in firefox the menu's top is bit down. There is an unwanted margin-top of 36px in .dropmenudiv class. Removing this made the submenu appear closer to the menu, and i was able to mouse over the submenu.

Comment: I can easily remove the margin-top in .dropmenudiv to make it work in Firefox, but then it wont work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute position:absolute causes this issue. Try this code instead what you have used.

http://jsfiddle.net/AAgfF/2/

Comment: I don't see a dropdown effect when trying out your code on the link provided.

Comment: you can see this menu worked fine in this site.http://campora.org/. The only js required is bizj_menu.js. Try this.